# rewrite rule works but does not stop when matched in .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I added the following rules in [.htaccess] file:

```
RewriteRule ^welcome/?$ index.php [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^bye/?$ bye.php [NC,L]  
RewriteRule ^.*/?$ error.html [NC,L]
```

when I enter http://localhost/welcome it goes to error page and not to index page.

But when I remove the last rule in .htaccess file, it shows the index page. Shouldn't it stop when matching with the first rule.

I want to prevent users from accessing the index page directly by typing in URL bar.

what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check for `REDIRECT_STATUS` in a separate rule to verify if rule has run once or not.

```
RewriteEngine On

# check if rules have run once
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# block direct access to index.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

# your default rules
RewriteRule ^welcome/?$ index.php [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^bye/?$ bye.php [NC,L]  
RewriteRule .* error.html [L]
```

Comment: you usually give excellent answers but in this case I think it's odd difficult. isn't it? :)

Comment: No it is not that difficult if you read 2 requirements from OP :)

Comment: but secound rule has no effects. because when i removed from htaccess it prevents direct access to index.php .  means the last rule works for preventing access to all other pages.

Comment: 2nd rule is only useful when some one enters URL as`http://example.com/index.php` and will get 403.